# Singleton Class design Issues

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

Below is a class using the singleton design pattern:

```
class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance;
    private Singleton()
    {
        ...
    }

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Singleton();

        return instance;
    }
    ...
    public void doSomething()
    {
        ... 
    }
}
```

I wanted to know some design issues about the above class? Why is the instance variable `instance` private and static. I understand that being private make the instance variable accessible only to object of that specific class but how does it help?

Comment: Added Java since I'm not aware of the synchronized keyword in c#.

Comment: Do you really need to instantiate it lazy?

Comment: @NoobUnChained i disagree this is a dup.  He's asking if there is anything wrong with this particular implementation, not what abuses of singleton could come about.

Answer (score 6):

If it was *public*, everybody could use `Singleton.instance` and would complain because it's null. Making it *private* forces them to use `getInstance()`, which guarantees to return a non-null instance.

If it wasn't *static*, it would be an instance variable of Singleton, and you would thus need a Singleton instance to access the unique Singleton instance which doesn't make much sense.